# How to plot chart with bars overlapped by time?

Tags: excel, graph

I'd like to plot a graph like that bellow using excel but i don't have any ideia how i can do it.

That graph is electric charges by a day time:
Load 1: 96 W, 24h/day;
Load 2: 72 W, 3 times a day (6h, 12h, 18h), duration of 1h;
Load 3: 48 W, every 2 hours for 6 min.

[image: desired graphic style]

Note: the graph is out of scale because it is just a sketch that I made quick to explain.

Comment: May find https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2013/charts/1/ useful to begin with.

Comment: I know how to make usual graphics in Excel... But that specific kind I dont know how

Comment: Can you provide the legend of your firgure and some example data?

Comment: Legend: Load 1: 96 W, 24h/day; Load 2: 72 W, 3 times a day (6h, 12h, 18h), duration of 1h; 
Load 3: 48 W, every 2 hours for 6 min.